# Add TagList in UITextField similar to native IOS Message App

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

In Native IOS Message App, In Adding contact from Address Book, there is one `UITextField` (might be) which will show added contacts as `TagList`. How can we create this? i mean, How to add Taglists in `UITextField`? A screenshot below may give an idea abou my question.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a couple of ready solutions on cocoa controls

[token fields](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=token)

Comment: Please add the actual answer

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom UIView class and bind delegate ,methods to add a Tag and remove a Tag.  Inside this view, each tag can be a UILabel or UIButton, and the UITextField is always pushed to the right, next to the last tag.

The important thing is, there's only 1 text field which will move along (the cursor blinking).
Hope it helps!